# chunking a large csv file by offset [0] in python

Tags: python, list, csv

I have a CSV file in the format:

```
1,data,data2,data3.....
1,data,data2,data3.....
2,data,data2,data3.....
2,data,data2,data3.....
3,data,data2,data3.....
3,data,data2,data3.....
```

I need to chunk these strings by offset[0] into a list such that I get multiple lists with:

```
1,data,data2,data3.....
1,data,data2,data3.....
```

and another:

```
2,data,data2,data3.....
2,data,data2,data3.....
```

etc. I have the following code:

```
import csv
filename = 'somefile.csv'
with open(filename) as csv_file:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    chunk1 = []
    for row in csv_file:
        if row[0] is '1':
            print(row)
        else:
            break
```

This gives only first chunk I need to adapt this to get all chunks of the same of set in lists.

Comment: Please reformat this, it's uneradable. Use code formating options (there's help button somewhere when editing). Name your data `a, b, c` or `foo, bar, theta` or something and not `data` and definitely not `1`. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming they're sorted by the first column, this will do it:

```
import csv

from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter


filename = 'somefile.csv'

with open(filename) as csv_file:
    csvreader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    chunks = [list(g) for k, g in groupby(csvreader, itemgetter(0))]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary to aggregate all of the chunks. Use an `OrderedDict` if you need to keep them in the order read.

```
import csv
filename = 'somefile.csv'
with open(filename) as csv_file:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    chunks = {}
    for row in csv_file:
        if row[0] not in chunks:
            chunks[row[0]] = []
        chunks[row[0]].append(row)
```

Comment: Can you elaborate? How would you use a dictionary to do this?

Comment: @Cyphase Example code posted that shows the chunks as a list of rows in a dictionary keyed by the element in the first column. Grab by `chunks[key]` or `chunks.values()`.